# Reading lines from a file in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I am banging my head against some syntax wall I think, and I'm not sure what's going wrong. I had a bash script that used to run on an older version of Redhat, but for some reason it's not running on our Linux server. In any case, I tried to update and here's what I have now...

UPDATED per comment suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line;
do
     echo "this is species no. $line";
done < "$1"
```

Ultimately, what I'll want this to do is pass those numbers to an R script, but no matter now. It doesn't seem to like the passing of a file at the end of the script (I get a "syntax error near unexpected token 'done'). However, when I take that out, it says "unexpected end of file." What's going wrong?

In case it matters, the server is running bash 4.2.25.

Comment: Change `filename = "$1"` to `filename="$1"`. There can be no spaces in assignments in bash.

Comment: Also, you don't actually need any variable assignment statements in this code: `while read -r bird; do echo "This is species no. $bird"; done < "$1"`.

Comment: You have some other syntax error which is not present in the code currently posted.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: works fine as long as an argument is given, and produces a different error if `$1` is null.

Comment: thanks for testing it. for completeness' sake, this is on Ubuntu 12.04 server. I'm running this by typing at the command prompt: bash birds.sh listofbirds.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your code is perfect, though I would probably put an IFS in there and drop the redundant semi-colon.

I suspect that the line endings in your file are causing the error. The script below should handle that... but the best way to know for sure would be to run your script with a new small test file of names.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(sed 's/^M$//' "$1")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I tried updating the script accordingly and still get the error "syntax error near unexpected token `done'". considering that @chepner can also not reproduce this error, I'm starting to wonder if it isn't a problem server-side. I've been wanting our dept to update to Tahr but they don't want to spend time on it. I'm just wondering if there is some sort of a glitch that would be fixed with an upgrade or something.

Comment: this ended up being a stupid Windows-to-Linux error: I made the text file in Windows and didn't realize the carriage return was the problem